# Error deploying JHipster with aws-containers on Windows 10

Tags: windows, jhipster

I'm trying to deploy a monolith JHipster demo on AWS using AWS-containers

```
c:\jhipster\demo>jhipster aws-containers
..
️ AWS configuring
√ ECR Auth token has been retrieved.
Run-async async() called outside a valid run-async context, callback will be ignored.
AWS default
Warning demo is using a cache provider, scaling will not be available. Refer to an AWS native scaling service.
    force ..\..\Users\demo\.yo-rc-global.json
identical pom.xml
identical src\main\java\com\demo\bootstrap\AwsSSMConfiguration.java
identical src\main\resources\META-INF\spring.factories
    force .yo-rc.json
identical src\main\resources\config\bootstrap-aws.yml
identical base.template.yml
identical demo.template.yml
Run-async wrapped function (sync) returned a promise but async() callback must be executed to resolve.
× ".." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
× The Docker image build failed. Error: Command failed: ../demo/./mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild
".." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

I'm using JHipster 6.10.5 on windows 10.

The output is partially on spanish, the translation is:

```
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

it's a environment issue caused by windows 10.

I see the same error at
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8366#issuecomment-489498566
Also looks like a windows machine.

Is trying to execute
../demo/./mvnw -ntp -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild

that not is a valid command on windows system.

Any idea about how fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure stackoverflow is the right place for this, you should open a new issue on jhipster's github repo with more details.

Comment: Thanks, @GaëlMarziou, done
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14262
I'm trying a workaround with WSL2, but is failing due other unrelated issue.